# Redirect to a div on a different page with smooth scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, razor, smooth-scrolling

**Question Background:**

I have a 2 page website. Both pages use the same **masterlayout.cshtml** page which features a Navbar. Within the Navbar is a number of links which scroll down to the relevant divs on page one based on their ID's.

**The Issue:**

When I access the second page I can no longer redirect to the specified divs from the Navbar links on the first page. This makes sense as the focus is no longer on the first page, but how do I get around this issue?

**Code:**

Here is the Navbar code with the div id's set, note the `data-id` attributes specifying which div to scroll to:

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="Welcome">Welcome</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="features">Club</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="About">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="Location">Location</a></li>
                <li><a href='@Url.Action("FutureEvents", "Events", new { pageNo = 1 })'>Events</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Example of a div that is scrolled to:

```
        <div id="Welcome">
             //HTML
        </div>
```

The JQuery used to Scroll to the relevant div:

```
        function scrollToID(id, speed) {
          var offSet = 70;
          var obj = $(id).offset();
          var targetOffset = $(id).offset().top - offSet;
          $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: targetOffset }, speed);
        }
```

If anyone can help with coming up with a viable solution to being able to call these id's from a different page that would be great.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using the data-id to set the id name? Could you not use the href such as <a href="#Welcome" class="scroll-link">Welcome</a>

Comment: @AaronVanston Thanks for your reply. I did think of using `a href` myself but I receive an error stating that the "Cannot resolve id 'Welcome' "

Comment: the links should include the file that they exist on if the navbar is to be shown on pages where the ID's don't exists, for example: <a href="masterlayout.cshtml#Welcome" class="scroll-link">Welcome</a>

Comment: @AaronVanston many thanks again for your reply. I tried specifying my master page `<li><a href="_Layout.cshtml#Welcome" class="scroll-link">Welcome</a></li>` but the ID still cannot be resolved.

Comment: It's not clear how those parts you provided interact with each other. The problem specification is not clear neither. When do you invoke the `scrollToID()` function? `onload`? `onclick`? Do you generate the nav link at server side or client side? what's the generated HTML of navbar? Do you get Javascript error when you click, after the "second page" has been loaded?

Comment: Have you tried using this yet?  `href="javascript:void(0);"`

Comment: When you have callad the "scrollToID()" function. have added called function in head tag directly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done with cookies. Setting a cookie with `id` you want to scroll, and then, when the new page is loaded, read the cookie and scroll to defined `id`. I used the very popular plugin [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

**Here is the JavaScript code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Read the cookie and if it's defined scroll to id
    var scroll = $.cookie('scroll');
    if(scroll){
        scrollToID(scroll, 1000);
        $.removeCookie('scroll');
    }

    // Handle event onclick, setting the cookie when the href != #
    $('.nav a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if(href === '#'){
            scrollToID(id, 1000);
        }else{
            $.cookie('scroll', id);
            window.location.href = href;
        }
    });

    // scrollToID function
    function scrollToID(id, speed) {
        var offSet = 70;
        var obj = $('#' + id);
        if(obj.length){
          var offs = obj.offset();
          var targetOffset = offs.top - offSet;
          $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: targetOffset }, speed);
        }
    }
});
```

**Here I have prepared a minimal example with this working:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/l2aassM4biyNRWNCrvUz?p=preview

Note: Click on `Events` to nav to the other page.

Comment: Thanks for your example. What I want is slightly different though. I want the user to be click the Events links which shows the events on page 2 then when they click on Welcome link it redirects back to the page 1 and scrolls down to the Welcome div on page 1.

Comment: @Imgonzalves Yes, there is no div with the ID welcome on the page2 this is only on page1. So I always need to redirect to page1 and then scroll to the relevant ID when on page2.

Comment: @Imgonzalves Thanks again for your time. I've checked the example but but when I click on the 'Welcome' link on page2 it does go back to page1 but does not scroll down to the div.

Comment: @Imgonzalves Thanks your example does indeed work. I have tried editing the example to remove the Events div on the second page. If I remove this then the scrolling to the welcome div no longer works, why is this?

Comment: @Imgonzalves Many thanks for your help. With a bit of tweaking of your example I've got this performing exactly how I needed. Again, thank you.

Comment: I'm glad to help! I delete extra comments to keep it clean.

Comment: I am getting "$.cookie is not a function" error. It didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can track hash of page url and scroll page to particular div

```
<a href="#Welcome" class="scroll-link">Welcome</a>
<a href="your_page_url#Welcome" class="other-page">Welcome</a> <!-- link to other page scroll div -->
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var speed = 1000;

    // check for hash and if div exist... scroll to div
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if($(hash).length) scrollToID(hash, speed); 

    // scroll to div on nav click
    $('.scroll-link').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
        if($(id ).length) scrollToID(id, speed);
    });
})

function scrollToID(id, speed) {
    var offSet = 70;
    var obj = $(id).offset();
    var targetOffset = obj.top - offSet;
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: targetOffset }, speed);
}
```

Comment: hello i have 2 anchor link and 2 part on same page.. This same page when i click other anchor links, there is no scroll effect  why? how can i use href="#Welcome" and href="your_page_url#Welcome"  together systematically

Answer (score 1):

How do you redirect to another page, using `href` value?

If so, also add in `data-id` for this `<a>` tag too.

So when you click on Events link, it will go to another html page and you want to scroll to Events div, right?

Then using `sessionStorage`, you can store and get  back the page id, then scroll to its specific div.

Add below script and let's see.

#### JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // get sessionStorage for page id
    var get_id = sessionStorage.getItem('pg_id');

    // check page id, then scroll to its div
    if(get_id)
        scrollToID(get_id, 300);

    // click event to scroll to div
    $('.nav li a').on('click', function(){
        var id = '#'+$(this).data('id');
        sessionStorage.setItem('pg_id', id);
        scrollToID(id, 300);
    }); 

});
function scrollToID(id, speed) {
    var offSet = 70;
    var obj = $(id).offset();
    var targetOffset = $(id).offset().top - offSet;
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: targetOffset }, speed);
}
```

#### HTML (My sample)

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="Welcome">Welcome</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="features">Club</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="About">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="Location">Location</a></li>
    <li><a href='page2.html' data-id="Event">Events</a></li>
    <!-- use your script to redirect to another page, but add "data-id" -->
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. I have changed data-id to id. You can use javascript.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" onclick="scrollme(this.id)" id="Welcome">Welcome</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" onclick="scrollme(this.id)" id="features">Club</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" onclick="scrollme(this.id)" id="About">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" onclick="scrollme(this.id)" id="Location">Location</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' onclick="scrollme(this.id)" id="Event">Events</a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript to scroll

```
function scrollme(id)
{
     var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');
     var targetOffset = $(id).offset().top;
      $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset-100}, 1000, function() {

          });
}
function scrollableElement(els)
{
    for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i <argLength; i++) {
      var el = arguments[i],
          $scrollElement = $(el);
      if ($scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0) {
        return el;
      } else {
        $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
        var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0;
        $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
        if (isScrollable) {
          return el;
        }
      }
    }
    return [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean. Than you can just do this what an iFrame.
In the Navbar for each tab just put a `href='#welcome'` or `href='#features'` and than give the iFrame for `welcome` a `ID` of `welcome`. When you click on the tab for `welcome`. You will be send to the iFrame with the `welcome` content. For `features` do the same and all following tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to create another nav bar for other page from where you want to redirect your end users

try this:

create a file first.php or first.html

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
.t{
    min-height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid;
}
</style>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="Welcome">Welcome</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="features">Club</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="About">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="Location">Location</a></li>
                <li><a href='@Url.Action("FutureEvents", "Events", new { pageNo = 1 })'>Events</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
<div id = 'Welcome' class="t">
</div>
<div id = 'features' class="t">
</div>
<div  id = 'About'class="t">
</div>
<div  id = 'Location' class="t">
</div>
<div id ='div_101' class="t">
scroll upto here
</div>
<script>

function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}


$(document).ready(function(){   
    var param_scroll = getParameterByName('id');
    if(param_scroll){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#"+param_scroll).offset().top
        }, 3000);   
    }
});


</script>
```

Then second file with different nav-bar

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="first_page.php?id=Welcome" class="scroll-link" data-id="Welcome">Welcome</a></li>
                <li><a href="first_page.php?id=features" class="scroll-link" data-id="features">Club</a></li>
                <li><a href="first_page.php?id=About" class="scroll-link" data-id="About">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="first_page.php?id=Location" class="scroll-link" data-id="Location">Location</a></li>
                <li><a href='@Url.Action("FutureEvents", "Events", new { pageNo = 1 })'>Events</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may use `$.cookie` every time you scroll on the first page.

For Example :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.scroll-link').on("click",function()
    {
       $.cookie('page',$(this).attr('data-id')); 
    });
    if($.cookie('page') != null || $.cookie('page') != "")
    {
        scrollToID($.cookie('page'), 1000);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send the ID of the div, that you want to scroll to, to the second page through a URL query string and write a script (in page 2) to read the URL and scroll to the specified div.
Piece of cake.