# Redirect from subdomain to main domain navbar dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, navbar

I've found a similar solution here [Redirect to a div on a different page with smooth scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518747/redirect-to-a-div-on-a-different-page-with-smooth-scrolling) but have tried to apply to my project and doesn't work.

So to recap - I'm using Bootstrap Navbar and ScrollTop smooth scroll and works fine on main page. (eg - example.com, example.com/#dropdown1 ).  Problem is when I go to subdomain (eg - example.com/user) and then click on the dropdown navbar menu option, it simply applies the '#dropdown1' to the end of the subdomain (eg - example.com/user/#dropdown1) and does not redirect.

I can change the `href` to `/#dropdown1` but then the smooth scroll no longer works.  It just jumps to the div regardless if on main or subdomain.  Relevant code below - please help.

I read somewhere to try data-targets, hence why it's here but this didn't work.

Application.html.erb

```
...
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bb-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Sellers <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#home" data-target="home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#dd1" data-target="dd1">dd1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#dd2" data-target="dd2">dd2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#dd3" data-target="dd3">dd3/a></li>

          </ul>
        </li><!--/.dropdown-->
</ul>
</div> 
...       
<script type="text/javascript">
          var $root = $('html, body');
            $('.navbar-nav a').click(function() {
                var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
                $root.animate({
                    scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
                }, 500, function () {
                    window.location.hash = href;
                });
                return false;
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post helped me get the answer. [Rails 4 / Bootstrap 3: how to display a different navigation bar on different pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31280230/rails-4-bootstrap-3-how-to-display-a-different-navigation-bar-on-different-pa)

I created a partial that had an alternate navbar for the subdomain pages and then executed this:

Layout/Application:

```
<body>
    <% if content_for?(:navbar) %>
        <%= yield(:navbar) %>
    <% else %>
       # code for default navbar
    <% end %>
</body>
```

Then in all of my subdomain pages views I did:

View:

```
 <% content_for :navbar do %>
      <%= render '_navbar_partial_name' %>
 <% end %>
```

The alternate navbar I just made a button that led to the home page and when landed on the homepage it automatically converted the button to the regular scrolling dropdown menu.