# Go back one page and scroll to div ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First off thanks for taking the time to read my question. I'm trying to make a normal link (href), link back one page and scroll to an div `id`. I've been looking at this question: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518747/redirect-to-a-div-on-a-different-page-with-smooth-scrolling). Which does exactly what I want. So I've linked the JavaScript file in my header and placed the jQuery code in my footer. But it does nothing.

This is my link:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
    <a href="/the_liked_page/" data-id="my_id" class="gobackandscroll"><i class="fa fa-th-large fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Go back</a>
</div>
```

Nothing fancy... and here is the script:

```
// Read the cookie and if it's defined scroll to id
var scroll = jQuery.cookie('scroll');
if(scroll){
    scrollToID(scroll, 1000);
    jQuery.removeCookie('scroll');
}

// Handle event onclick, setting the cookie when the href != #
jQuery('.gobackandscroll').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = jQuery(this).data('id');
    var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    if(href === '#'){
        scrollToID(id, 1000);
    }else{
        jQuery.cookie('scroll', id);
        window.location.href = href;
    }
});

// scrollToID function
function scrollToID(id, speed) {
    var offSet = 65;
    var obj = jQuery('#' + id).offset();
    var targetOffset = obj.top - offSet;
    jQuery('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: targetOffset }, speed);
};
```

I don't get any errors in my console.log and it links to the page I want. But there is no scrolling.

When I delete all the data and mark up both pages like this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/l2aassM4biyNRWNCrvUz?p=preview it does work. So the JavaScript is correctly loaded and storing the cookie.

So I thought maybe the data-id is not stored so I've put an alert on the click using:

```
alert(id);
```

This gives the correct `data-id` but this doesn't scroll on the next page. Does anyone have an idea why this isn't working or a better suggestion for this? Thanks of the help...

Comment: When does this script get executed, especially the first part that is supposed to do the scrolling? Does the element with the ID this is looking for already exist in the DOM at this point …?

Comment: Yes everything already exists when the script is fired. Thats the reason I placed this script in the footer aswel. (I've been tinkering around with this script. And right now I just deleted everything from the page and no I get `(index):295 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined` and that's bothering me now :)